# How do I redirect users from a specific country?

Tags: javascript, redirect, geolocation

I would like to be able to detect if visitors to a webpage are situated in the USA and if they are I would like to redirect them to a different page.

I've been googling for some script that could do this but haven't found anything. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'd ideally like to be able to achieve it with Javascript and/or HTML5 but if that's not possible  please do let me know about alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tutorial from here: [GeoDirection](http://www.geobytes.com/GeoDirection)

```
<script language="Javascript" src="http://gd.geobytes.com/gd?after=-1&variables=GeobytesLocationCode,GeobytesCode,GeobytesInternet"></script>
<script language="Javascript">
if(typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode)=="undefined"
   ||typeof(sGeobytesCode)=="undefined"
   ||typeof(sGeobytesInternet)=="undefined")
{
   // Something has gone wrong with the variables, so set them to some default value,
   // maybe set a error flag to check for later on.
   var sGeobytesLocationCode="unknown";
   var sGeobytesCode="unknown";
   var sGeobytesInternet="unknown";
}
if(sGeobytesLocationCode=="GRATATHE")
{
   // Visitors from Athens would go here
   window.open("enter Athens URL here");
}else if(sGeobytesCode=="AT")
{
   // Visitors from Attiki would go here
   window.open("enter Attiki URL here");
}else if(sGeobytesInternet=="GR")
{
   // Visitors from Greece would go here
   window.open("enter Greece URL here");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some scripts to solve your problem (in PHP): http://www.phptutorial.info/iptocountry/the_script.html

Summary:

1. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = variable to detect IP address of visitor
2. download list of IP address ranges on page above (you can choose specific list of countries or download all countries) - each country has range of IP addreses

aletrnative solution is to use webservice http://freegeoip.net/, but there is daily limit for requests.

Comment: From the [Help Center / How to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) : Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Also, these are PHP scripts.